# opencv error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv

I wanna crop the image within the coordinates of rectangle from object detection. Are there any problems in my x,y coordinates ? The rectangle can be drawn but the image cannot be cropped.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 

image = cv2.imread('venv/img.jpg')

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('n').split('n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0 / 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(image, confThreshold=0.5)

print(classIds, bbox)
if len(classIds) != 0:
    for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(), confs.flatten(), bbox):
        cv2.rectangle(image, box, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        print(bbox)
        x1=box[0]
        y1=box[1]
        x2=box[2]
        y2=box[3]
        crop_person = image[y1:y2,x1:x2]
        cv2.imshow('img',crop_person)
        cv2.waitKey(0)


image = cv2.resize(image,(480,640))
cv2.imshow('img',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the result of printing bbox is shown below:

```
[[384 617 218 731]
 [ 45 722 188 472]
 [568 648 251 622]
 [767 691 165 528]
 [888 615 131 537]
 [232 657 187 545]
 [ 27 598 128 475]
 [168 590  98 169]
 [782 573 137 301]
 [795 667 186 499]
 [150 717 117 472]
 [227 628 312 672]]
```

So,I think the coordinates in the bbox can be used directly.

Comment: maybe the box is `(cx, cy, w, h)` -- **complete traceback is required**. please review [mre]. -- I don't think this is an imread issue, or OP would have complained about earlier steps than the cropping

Comment: Check box parameters. Maybe it isnt x2/y2 but width/height, then you will need x2=x1+box[2] and 
        y2=y1+box[3]

Comment: `[(i,j,(bbox[:,i] <= bbox[:,j]).all()) for i in range(4) for j in range(i+1,4)]` results in `[(0, 1, False), (0, 2, False), (0, 3, False), (1, 2, False), (1, 3, False), (2, 3, True)]` -- can you see what that tells you about the meaning of these columns? it means you DO NOT HAVE "x2, y2" there. those must be width and height, or your network is broken. YOU must know what type of data your network emits.

Answer (score 0):

Print the Xs and Ys, see if they didn't create a 0 area rectangle.
You can also change the imshow part to be:

```
if (y2-y1)*(x2-x1) > 0:
  cv2.imshow(....)
```

Also, make sure that y2 is actually greater than y1 (same goes to x).

Comment: Yup. x2 is greater than x1. y2 is greater than y1. You can see the result of print(bbox) as follows. [[384 617 218 731]
 [ 45 722 188 472]
 [568 648 251 622]
 [767 691 165 528]
 [888 615 131 537]
 [232 657 187 545]
 [ 27 598 128 475]
 [168 590  98 169]
 [782 573 137 301]
 [795 667 186 499]
 [150 717 117 472]
 [227 628 312 672]]

Comment: But   218 (x2?) is smaller than 384 (x1?) In your first box?!?

Comment: Well, if your bbox is what you've just mentioned, then box[0] isn't an x coordinate. It's [x0, y0, x1, y1]. Every row is a set of coordinates.